# Why can 'notwithstanding' be positioned before or after the object without changing meaning?

Tags: english, historical-linguistics, prepositions

Please explain 'notwithstanding', only in terms of the adverb 'not' and the root verb 'withstand'.

> [ [Grammarist:](http://grammarist.com/usage/notwithstanding/) ] ***Notwithstanding*** is mainly a [preposition](http://grammarist.com/grammar/prepositions/) meaning *in spite of*. Most dictionaries also list it as an [adverb](http://grammarist.com/grammar/adverbs/) meaning *nevertheless,* but this sense is rarely used in modern English. *Notwithstanding* is always one word, and this has been the standard spelling for many centuries.
>
> Although *notwithstanding* usually means exactly the same as *in spite of*, it is often positioned differently. *In spite of* always comes before its object—e.g., “In spite of your feedback, I’m not changing anything.” **But *notwithstanding* is often postpositive, meaning it comes after its object**—e.g., “Your feedback notwithstanding, I’m not changing anything.” **Of course, it can come before its object as well**—e.g., “Notwithstanding your feedback, I’m not changing anything.”

[This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/216438/50720) explains: 'notwithstanding' etymologically signifies 'not standing against' or 'can't withstand'. Then I intuited  **notwithstanding**'s signification to vary by position:

1. **Notwithstanding** X, Y (happens) = **Can't withstand** X, Y. = Y, **can't withstand** X.
2. X **notwithstanding**, Y.  = X **can't withstand**, Y.

But 1 is wrong, because 1 signifies the same as 2. So what is wrong with my intuition?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, *notwithstanding* is a literary or legal term that doesn't enter into the spoken language much, so you can practically depend on its having weird syntax.

Second, *notwithstanding* is a transparent polymorphemic word ***[not-  [[with-  stand]  -ing]]*** based on the present participle of the verb *withstand*; it's treated as a verb in this word by using *not*- instead of *un*- as the negative prefix.

Third, the etymology of this particular *with*- prefix does not come from the preposition *with* meaning 'together', but rather from a different preposition we no longer have in English that meant 'against' -- pretty much the opposite of 'with'. German still has that preposition (*wider* 'against', which takes an Accusative object), and it also has the verb *widerstehen* 'to resist, withstand', formed with the German verb *stehen* 'stand'.

Fourth, the noun phrase that's marked by *notwithstanding* in either position functions as the subject of *notwithstanding*. I.e, if the sentence is

- *`X` *notwithstanding, `Y`*,

then  `X` is the subject that did **not** stand against (and thus disqualify) `Y`, and therefore `X` can be ignored from now on.

Finally, a word as big and transparent as *notwithstanding* is likely to become an adverb indicating the importance of a particular piece of evidence, and like most adverbs, its position is subject to the whims of the speaker and can certainly modify a verb phrase.

To answer the presenting question, no, there's no consistent difference between the phrases

- *Notwithstanding `X`,*

and

- *`X` notwithstanding.*

(both of which can occur at either the beginning or the end of a sentence)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps,  in BOTH 1 and 2 , Y is the thing that fails to withstand ( Y being the ' implicit subject ' of the phrases containing the word ' notwithstanding '  as well as the '  explicit subject ' of the main clauses ) and the positioning makes no difference to that fact . So there's no difference in meaning in REALITY and both actually mean ' Y can't withstand X ' .  If your intuition is therefore to be considered erroneous , might it be because the word order in 2 erroneously suggests to your intuition that X is the subject ( because subjects are usually in first position ) and that your intuition is therefore labouring under a delusion ?